# Tabular output from Excel2latex going off the page

Tags: tabularx

I've used excel2Latex to convert a table into tabular format. The code generated is this

```
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{rlrrrr}
    \toprule
          &       & Start date & End date & Days spent \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{6}[12]{*}{\textbf{Background research}}} & Research which existing technologies exist for recommendation systems & 06/10/2011 & 10/10/2011 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{6}[12]{*}{22}} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & Investigate the problems being face by the current recommender systems & 11/10/2011 & 15/10/2011 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & Learn what Semantic Web is and how the it is being implemented to solve problems & 16/10/2011 & 20/10/2011 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & Investigate how semantic web is being used for recommendation systems & 16/10/2011 & 20/10/2011 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & Read research papers on to find out more on work about music recommendation that has already been done in the past & 21/10/2011 & 27/10/2011 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & Deliverable: Write a literature survey to summarize research findings & 21/10/2011 & 28/10/2011 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{5}{r}{}                  & \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}[8]{*}{\textbf{Analysis \& Design}}} & Create a structured list of requirements from the problem statement & 29/10/2011 & 04/11/2011 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{6}} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & Deliverable produced: Create a structured list of requirements from the problem statement & 29/10/2011 & 04/11/2011 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & Begin prototyping and experimenting with Semantic Web & 05/11/2011 & 09/12/2011 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{34}} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & Deliverable produced: A basic prototype of the recommender system & 05/11/2011 & 09/12/2011 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{5}{r}{}                  & \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{21}[42]{*}{\textbf{Implementation}}} & \textbf{Iteration 1  - Implementing and testing core functionality of the website} &       &       &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & Let users register with the website & 10/12/2011 & 16/12/2011 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{7}[14]{*}{34}} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & Simulate users listening to songs/albums & 10/12/2011 & 16/12/2011 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & Enable searching for music and playlists in the website & 17/12/2011 & 23/12/2011 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & Let users create playlists and add/remove songs to them & 24/12/2011 & 30/12/2011 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & Users can integrate with Facebook and find friends that are also registered on the website & 31/12/2011 & 06/01/2012 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & Users can comment on a playlist and Like a playlist & 07/01/2012 & 13/01/2012 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & Deliverable produced: The first iteration of the website without a recommendation system & 10/12/2011 & 13/01/2012 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{4}{r}{}          & \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textbf{Iteration 2 - Implemented and testing core functionality of the algorithm} &       &       &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & Integrate Semantic Web so that recommendation algorithm can be implemented & 14/01/2012 & 20/01/2012 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{5}[10]{*}{27}} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & The website shall allow users to get music recommendations based on the friend’s taste & 21/01/2012 & 03/02/2012 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & The website shall allow users to get music recommendations based on the user’s taste & 21/01/2012 & 10/02/2012 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & Deliverables produced: Algorithm for music recommendation & 14/01/2012 & 10/02/2012 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & Second iteration of the website with core functionality in place & 14/01/2012 & 10/02/2012 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{4}{r}{}          & \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textbf{Iteration 3 - Adding additional features (Could have's and Wont have's in the requirements)} &       &       &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & Carry out the finishing touches of the website & 11/02/2012 & 24/02/2012 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}[8]{*}{13}} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & View a feed which lets them find out what their friends are doing on the site through likes and comments & 11/02/2012 & 17/02/2012 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & Allow users to subscribe to a playlist & 18/02/2012 & 24/02/2012 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & Deliverable: Final version of the website with added features & 11/02/2012 & 24/02/2012 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{5}{r}{}                  & \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}[3]{*}{\textbf{Documentation}}} & Begin the final report & 25/02/2012 & 30/03/2012 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}[3]{*}{34}} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & Deliverable: Final report with explaining all stages of the software development cycle & 25/02/2012 & 30/03/2012 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
```

The text doesn't get wrapped and it goes off the page. I tried setting the width for the second cell but it didn't work. How can I make it fit into page width?

Also how can I make the table overflow go to the next page once the page gets filled up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change some of the r or l in the tabular preamble to `p{3cm}`  or whatever width looks best for you.

Then change

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{rlrrrr}
```

To something like

```
\begin{longtable}{rlrp{2cm}p{2cm}p{2cm}}
 \caption{Add caption}
```

and load the `longtable` package

Comment: Thanks, I tried this {p{1cm}p{5cm}rp{2cm}p{2cm}p{0cm}} but the first column's width is unaffected

Comment: most (all?) of the first column is in multicolumn commands that over-ride the column specifier from the preamble, so youd need to make equivalent changes to the multicolumn commands. `\multicolumn{1}{c}{}` doesn't do anything at all though you could just delete those.